# Add a row with calculations in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This feels like a very basic question, but I've been struggling with it. Simplified version follows. I have the following dataset:

```r
a <- c('I' , 'E')
ja <- c(30 , 20)
fe <- c(50, 40)
ma <- c(35 , 22)

x <- data.frame(a, ja , fe , ma)
x
#>   a ja fe ma
#> 1 I 30 50 35
#> 2 E 20 40 22
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I want to add a row 3 to have the figures of row I minus row E for ja, fe and ma. So row 3 will look like:

```r
a     ja   fe   ma
I_E   10   10   13
```

There will be 12 columns, one for each month, so ideally I'd like to be able to refer to them concisely, for instance, as (in this example) ja:ma or the like. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try this `cbind(a = paste0(x[1:2,1], collapse = "_"), x[1,-1] - x[2,-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
x %>% 
  bind_rows(x %>% summarise(a = str_c(a, lead(a), sep = '_')) %>% na.omit() %>% 
                bind_cols(x %>% summarise(across(2:4, ~ . - lead(.))) %>% na.omit()))
    a ja fe ma
1   I 30 50 35
2   E 20 40 22
3 I_E 10 10 13
```

Comment: Many thanks, this worked perfectly for my somewhat more complex actual case. I'm familiar with some of the code but not all. Is there a reference for the code you can point me to?

Comment: @David, thanks, for reference, you may go through these links: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html  and https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

Data.frames are not Excel tables.

The R way is to have each row as a month.  You would start with 3 columns: month_name, I, and E.  Then you can create a 4th column that is a I minus E.

```
df <- data.frame(
    month_name = c("ja", "fe", "ma"),
    I = c(30, 50, 35),
    E = c(20, 40, 22)
)

df$E_E <- df$I - df$E
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table` approaches

```
library(data.table)   
rbind(setDT(x), x[, c(list(a = 'I_E'), 
      lapply(.SD, function(x) diff(rev(x)))), .SDcols = 2:4])
#     a ja fe ma
#1:   I 30 50 35
#2:   E 20 40 22
#3: I_E 10 10 13
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not nearly as familiar with data.table as I am with tidyverse packages. Karthnik's post solved my immediate time-sensitive problem but I'm energized to become more familiar with data.table.

Comment: @David Thank you.  It would be great investment if you get into the data.table package as it would be more efficient in dealing with different transformations